# How to reject blank and empty attributes during sign_up form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, hstore

I have

**Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  validates :email,
    presence: true

  serialize :data, ActiveRecord::Coders::Hstore

  %w[zipcode first_name].each do |key|
    attr_accessible key

    define_method(key) do
      data && data[key]
    end

    define_method("#{key}=") do |value|
      self.data = (data || {}).merge(key => value)
    end
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @user = User.find_or_initialize_by_email(params[:user][:email])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      redirect_to :back, notice: "Thanks for sign up!"
    else
      render "pages/home"
    end
  end
end
```

**View** with client side validation

```
<%= simple_form_for User.new, validate: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up' %>
<% end %>
```

First question: I would like to update existing user record but not if param is `""` or `" "`, how to achieve this?

Second question: Should I use `create` action to do that? Maybe `update` will be more clear. But this form also create an user object.

Third question: Is any chance to add `uniqueness` validation to email attribute? Right now my client-side validation do not allow do that.

Answer (score 1):

First: To disallow updating a field with empty strings, set `allow_blank: false` you could also do `allow_nil: false`. Add these to your validations in your model.

Second: N/A

Third: Simply add `uniqueness: true` to your email validation in your model.

Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html)

Comment: but what if i want this behaviour for all attributes stored in hstore data  column?

Comment: That was not in your original post. I answered the questions you initially presented.